# What is the effect of very small AC frequency deviations from the grid on invertors and transformers for normal comsumer objects?

Tags: transformer, inverter, power-engineering

What additional wear or inefficiencies are there from inverting a AC signal  to DC from say, 59.99 hertz instead of 60.00 hertz? And is there additional wear on transformers?  How do small deviations from 60 hertz negatively affect equipment?

Comment: the effect is "Very small" :)

Comment: Why does 0.01Hz concern you when a 1Hz change is 100x worse , yet still only <17% deaccleration of frequency and dynamic load current compared to the current when starting at stopped motor

Comment: Because real electrical grids are more frequently going to have these smaller deviations.

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant effect on other than old-fashioned synchronous-motor clocks and timers, it’s more important that all the power sources are at the same frequency and very similar phase. If the frequency were to wobble rapidly there might be other effects but that’s unlikely with conventional fossil fuel, hydroelectric or nuclear power.